# Italicizing content pane titles

Tags: 7, panels

A few of our content pane titles need to be italicized because they contain book titles.

I've added an "italicize-title" class to the content pane in Panelizer > Content > Content Pane > CSS properties. This has some drawbacks. The main disadvantages are that the whole title is italicized and I have to manually add the class to each piece of content needing its title italicized.

I've tried the [HTML Title](http://drupal.org/project/html_title) module, but that didn't work.

Is there a way for me to allow content editors to use a limited number of html tags in a content pane's title field?

Thank you for looking...

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I would try implementing a [`template_preprocess_panels_pane()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!panels!panels.module/function/template_preprocess_panels_pane/7):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars) {
  $content = &$vars['content'];

  $title = !empty($content->title) ? $content->title : '';
  $title = preg_replace("/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/", "<b>$1</b>", $title);
  $title = preg_replace("/\*(.*?)\*/", "<i>$1</i>", $title);

  $vars['title'] = $title;
}
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019187/php-preg-replace-to-turn-xyz-to-bxyz-b), and would allow some simple markdown in the titles.

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately. It just displays the `**Hello** World` verbatim instead of replacing it with the <b> tags.